# jQuery Datepicker - Enable specific day if already disabled

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery Datepicker successfully where I can disable all Sundays plus any other specified days. See below code.

```
<script>

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#date").datepicker({
    minDate: 0, maxDate: "+2M",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
});

var unavailableDates = ["8-2-2016"];  

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        return noSunday(date);
    }
}

function noSunday(date){
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day > 0), ''];
    }; 
});

</script>
```

I am trying to somehow enable a specific Sunday (Valentine's Day) to allow customer orders/deliveries on that day. Is there an easy way of tweaking my existing code to allow for this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function `noSunday` :

```
function noSunday(date){
 if(date == '14-02-2016'){
     return [1,''];
 }
 else{ 
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day > 0), ''];
 }
}; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your return for February 14th

```
return [(day > 0) || (date.getMonth() == 1 && date.getDate() == 14), ''];
```

This should also work for future Sunday Valentine's Day.